# automate getting diagnostic files from a controller via ssh commands

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I'd like to automate getting diagnostic files from a controller that responds to ssh commands, like e.g.

```
ssh diag@controller tarred > diags.tgz
```

Unfortunately, I have to type a password to make the above command go through. 
What have I considered to get around that:

1. using ssh keys: not possible, since I can't login to the controller, it just expects commands and doesn't offer a shell
2. using ssh-pass package: I don't have admin rights on the machine and can't install packages
3. using "expect": works to some extent, but the resulting file is corrupted.

Here's the "expect" script I've used:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_user 0
set timeout 300
spawn ssh diag@controller tarred
expect "?assword:"
send "unrealpassword\r"
expect \r\n
log_user 1
expect eof
```

The script makes sure that only the required output gets stored with the "log_user" commands until eof is encountered.

I've piped this script to a file and that file is corrupted, i.e. it's either too short (because of a timeout?) or too long (?).
Any idea about what goes wrong here.?

Comment: In addressing #1 ssh keys, have you tried using ssh-copy-id? I'm not sure if that will work without shell on the remote, but might be worth a try.

Comment: [ssh passwordless](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) might be your solution.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use keys or ssh-copy-id since this would require access to a shell on the server. The server doesn't provide that, it's configured to execute certain predefined commands only